# I have a mongodb query and I want to find the exact match word "Approved"

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongodb query and I want to find the exact match word "Approved" in Array named "Sales.Action".

But the array contains also other values other then the value "Approve" which also return when i query.

I want only one action to return.

Sample:

```
{
   Sales: [
       {Action: "Approve"},
       {Action: "Other"}
   ]
}
```

Required output:

```
{
   Sales: [
       {Action: "Approve"},
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your query as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one match you should use the [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document.

Use it like so:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        "Sales.Action": "Approve"
    },
    {
        "Sales.$": 1
    }
)
```

If you want to array in each document to possibly contain more than 1 result use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "Sales.Action": "Approve"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Sales: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Sales",
                    as: "obj",
                    cond: {$setIsSubset: [["Approve"], "$$obj.Action"]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I have already done that. But, I want to use array filter in query. Can you show that to me??.

Comment: array filters are used to update a document, you want to use the Aggregated command $filter you mean?

Comment: Yes. I want to use it.

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: There are four different arrays in Sales.Action which is Approve. And 1 array which is Approved. There are total of 5 arrays in Sales. In that there is another Array named Action. That is what I'm talking about. I want to use array filter to it.

Comment: My similar question can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422641/i-have-a-mongodb-query-and-i-want-to-find-the-exact-match-word-approved. Please help.

Comment: I changed the `$eq` into `$in` in the `$filter`

Comment: It says invalid operator $in. You can see JSON here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422641/i-have-a-mongodb-query-and-i-want-to-find-the-exact-match-word-approved for your reference. And please add answer on there.

Comment: Sorry i forgot that `$in` is not supported in the aggregation language, i used `$setIsSubset` instead. but the idea is the same