# I have a mongodb query and I want to find the exact match word “Approved”

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query and I want to find the exact match word "Approved" in Array named "Sales.Action".

But the other "Sales.Action" array has the value "Approve" which is also returning.

I have tried  $elemMatch but still it is not working.

Here is my json:

```
{
"Sales" : [
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approved"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/23/2020 44:04:04"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

But I need only one to return.

Comment: please show me what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this code i think this works for you

```
db.getCollection('your_collection').aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$Sales' },
  {
    $match: {'Sales.Action': 'Approve' }
  },
])
```

Comment: You have to Search and show only Action for Sales which Action is Approve. Can You Please Solve this thing?

Comment: your question what ?. 
you want to find exact match word "Approved" in Array named "Sales.Action". right ?

Comment: Search and show only Action for Sales which Action is Approve?. this is my question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please do one more thing for me? I have one question that is "Update the Action to Denied for sale which meets <some random invoice number>"?. Can you solve this?. Its in mongodb.

Comment: I  can't understand your comment .sorry

Comment: Can you do the above answer by using array filter please?

Comment: give me your exact output you want

Comment: Output would be same like you did for approved thing but I need to use array filter??

Comment: {
   Sales: [
       {Action: "Approved"},
   ]
}

Comment: But I need to use the array filter in your answer??/

Comment: But I need to use the array filter in your answer??/

Comment: Can you do this with array filter?

Comment: I can't understand array filter !

give me one example of array filter

Comment: Can you please solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424264/i-have-a-mongodb-query-and-i-want-to-update-the-action-to-denied-for-sale-which