# I have a mongodb query and I want to update the action to denied for Sale which meets <some random invoice number>

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query and I want to update the action to denied for Sale which meets

I want to update the action to denied.

I have tried several other methods but still it is not working.

Here is my json:

```
{

"Sales" : [ 
    {  
        "InvoiceNumber" : "Temp-ObjectID(\"5e9cb6c6ad4f2a0ef06ae159\")",
        "Action" : [ 
            "Approved"
        ],
        "Log" : [ 
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    }, 
    {

        "InvoiceNumber" : "Temp-ObjectID(\"5e9cbe20287628f1cbf78fdb\")",
        "Action" : [ 
            "Approve", 
            "Decline", 
            "Edit", 
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [ 
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "InvoiceNumber" : "Temp-ObjectID(\"5e9df32ffbcd19d39250c6e8\")",
        "Action" : [ 
            "Approve", 
            "Decline", 
            "Edit", 
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [ 
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    }, 
    {

        "InvoiceNumber" : "Temp-ObjectID(\"5e9df3bb41034effca69f86e\")",
        "Action" : [ 
            "Approve", 
            "Decline", 
            "Edit", 
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [ 
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    }, 
    {

        "InvoiceNumber" : "Temp-ObjectID(\"5ea173752b1baad5dfdf4023\")",
        "Action" : [ 
            "Approve", 
            "Decline", 
            "Edit", 
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [ 
            "Created on: 04/23/2020 44:04:04"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to update the action to denied. I want to use array filter in it and do that.

Comment: Can you please provide the query you are using

Comment: The query I'm using is the above query.

Comment: I want to update my action to denied with some invoice number

Comment: That's not a query. That is a sample data you will get after running your query

Comment: Its a JSON. I need to update my action to denied with some invoice number. I need mongodb query on that.

Comment: You should mention that you need a query. But your question says you have a query. Please make sure that your question is correct before posting